# How to avoid UnauthorizedAccessException on .Net framework?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to export some data to a txt file, but it doesn't work since I get unauthorized exception.

I tried running visual studio as admin, but it didn't work

This is the code I have:

```
  TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter(path);
  for (int i = 0; i < Movies.Count; i++)
  {
     txt.WriteLine(Movies[i].title);
  }
  txt.Close();
```

The path is correct

Comment: What is the value of `path`? Does your user have access to that file? Does the exception have any additional information? Is the file currently in use by another (or the same) process?

Comment: @gunr2171 I'm trying to export the file to my desktop, and the exception says: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access denied for 'C:\Users\user\Desktop'.'

Comment: Desktop is a _folder_. You're trying to write to a folder?

Comment: Show how you build the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to validate your path. If your path is a folder, you need to append a filename:

```cs
//check if folder exists
if(!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}

//append filename
var filepath = Path.Combine(path, "myfile.txt");

//write file
TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter(filepath);
  
for (int i = 0; i < Movies.Count; i++)
{
   txt.WriteLine(Movies[i].title);
}

txt.Close();
```

Do not attempt to write directly to a folder, that's probably whats causing the exception. You always need to provide a valid path to a file to write to.

Comment: You might also want to wrap your code with a try-catch block if you're not certain about the validity of certain paths, depending on your use cases.

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory` is a no-op if the directory already exists, so no need for `Directory.Exists` (and anyway, that'd be a race condition regardless).